# depend not working in system.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, system.xml, system-config

I created `system.xml` file like below and set all fields depend on `active` field but some of them doesn't work and display even `active` field is ***disabled***

system.xml

```
<fields>
    <active translate="label">
        <label>Enabled</label>
        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </active>
    <get_settings translate="label">
        <label>Account Info</label>
        <frontend_type>label</frontend_type>
        <frontend_model>module/adminhtml_settings</frontend_model>
        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <depends><active>1</active></depends>
    </get_settings>
    <title translate="label">
        <label>Title</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>4</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <depends><active>1</active></depends>
    </title>
    ....
```

in above file `get_settings` doesn't work but `title` work as well !
What is different between them?

and Settings.php in `module/adminhtml_settings`

```
class Name_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Settings extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
    ....
    ....
    return $html;
    }
}
```

but didn't use `$element` in codes!

Comment: How does the frontend model class for `get_settings` looks like? I mean `module/adminhtml_settings`. I bet that has something to do with your issue.

Comment: @Marius: I updated code in first code, I test it with "Alan Storm" http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial for `frontend_model` like "Last Update" , it do not work too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested your code and it seems to work fine on the `title` config. It doesn't work on the `get_settings` config because the Javascript that does the behind the scenes work requires that you have an input field with the correct ID.

So to get this to work, you would have to add a hidden input field, can be a dummy input field if you like, but the id must follow your config settings, so i would suggest you inspect element on one of the other input fields and follow suit

To do this just your `Settings.php` with the following:

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $html = $element->getElementHtml();
    $html .= '<input id="name_module_get_settings" name="groups[module_name][fields][titles][value]" value="" class=" input-text" type="hidden">';

    /** do what ever you want here **/

    return $html;
}
```

Thats it. Remember, the depends tag only works when there is an input field available in the source with the correct id's.

Comment: Great job, your answer is true!